# Find the magnitude Centripetal acceleration of a particle and the speed v

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

A particle P of mass m moves under the action of the force F~ (~r) = −βm/r^3 * ~ r, where ~r is the position vector of the particle with respect to the origin O, r = |~r|, β is a positive constant.

Assume that the orbit of P is a circle of radius R. Find the magnitude of the
centripetal acceleration and the speed v of the particle P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration is, of course, Force divided by mass.  Here force is $\frac{-\beta m}{r^3}\vec{r}$ so the acceleration is $\frac{-\beta}{r^3}\vec{r}$ so has magnitude $\frac{-\beta}{R^2}$.

If an object is moving in a circle of radius R then we can write its position, relative to the center of the circle, as $Rcos(vt)\vec{i}+ Rsin(vt)\vec{j}$.  Its velocity vector is the derivative of that, $-Rvsin(vt)\vec{i}+ Rvcos(vt)\vec{j}$ and its acceleration vector is $-Rv^2cos(vt)\vec{i}-Rv^2sin(vt)\vec{j}$.  The absolute value is $Rv^2= \frac{\beta}{R^2}$ so $v^2= \frac{\beta}{R^3}$ and $v= \frac{\beta^\frac{1}{2}}{R^\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: Thanks, the first part clears things up can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Because the body is on a circular path with a radius $R$ then we have that the magnitude of the centripetal and gravitational force are equal:
$$F=\frac{\beta m}{R^2}=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$

Comment: Should it not be R^3 at the bottom? Also thank you for the hint I got the speed now.

Comment: @Maths479 No, because the force is propotional to $$\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r} \frac{1}{r^2}$$, and $$\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$$ is just an unit vector, so $$\frac{1}{r^2}$$ will be in the magnitude only.

Comment: Okay and then I just rearrange for v.

Comment: @Maths479 that's right.